# "Don't set props of the React component" warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting this React.js error I'd love to know how to fix it. Is there a way to call `React.cloneElement` on `this`?

> Warning: Don't set .props.children of the React component . Instead, specify the correct value when initially creating the element or use React.cloneElement to make a new element with updated props. The element was created by Seven.

[Here's a full working example.](https://jsbin.com/jofusa/3/edit?js,console,output)

Here's my code:

```
var Thead = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Thead',
  propTypes: function () {
    return {
      children: React.propTypes.node
    }
  },
  componentWillMount: function () {
    this.childTr = containsElement('tr', this.props.children)
    this.props.children = reconcileChildren('th',
      (this.childTr) ? this.childTr.props.children : this.props.children,
      this.props.data
    )
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <thead>
        {this.childTr ? <tr {...this.childTr.props}>
          {this.props.children}
        </tr> : <tr>
          {this.props.children}
        </tr>}
      </thead>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: `this.props.children = reconcileChildren`, you're altering `prop` on this line, which is strongly discouraged. Props should only be passed by parents, and you may have to use something else to store those children.

Comment: Is `reconcileChildren` simply choosing between `this.props.children` and `this.childTr.props.children`?

Comment: @DavinTryon No it's not for it's full output you can check it out [here](https://jsbin.com/jofusa/3/edit?js,console,output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @fuyushimoya said in the comments is discouraged to alter `props` (which I didn't know) I set the children to `this.children` instead.

```
var Thead = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Thead',
  propTypes: function () {
    return {
      children: React.propTypes.node
    }
  },
  componentWillMount: function () {
    this.childTr = containsElement('tr', this.props.children)
    this.children = reconcileChildren('th',
      (this.childTr) ? this.childTr.props.children : this.props.children,
      this.props.data
    )
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <thead>
        {this.childTr ? <tr {...this.childTr.props}>
          {this.children}
        </tr> : <tr>
          {this.children}
        </tr>}
      </thead>
    )
  }
})
```